# KVC Compliant a Class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, kvc

When reading KVC Compliant in iOS document. I have tried to test a class. Is the KVC Class compliant?

But I have some questions:

1. No setters for properties "Name", "Age", and the class is still using KVC without error
   and no exception will be fired
2. When no setters are created for properties, what does the compiler do?  Does it
   create the pair of setter and getter?

   Person.h

   ```
   @interface Person : NSObject
   {
       NSString *name;
       NSInteger age;
   }
   ```

   Person.m

   ```
   @implementation Person

   - (id)init
   {
       self = [super init];
       if (self) {
           name = @"Duc Nguyen";
           age = 10;
       }
       return self;
   }
   ```

   ViewController.m

   ```
   - (IBAction)showKeyKVC:(id)sender {
       //--test kvc
       name1.text = [person valueForKey:@"name"];
       age1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [person valueForKey:@"age"]];
   }
   ```

When I pressed on button the result is: Age: 10, Name: Duc Nguyen. 
I don't understand how the class could use KVC in this case?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in the [Accessor Search Patterns for Simple Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA) KVC guide.

> **Default Search Pattern for setValue:forKey:**
>
> When the default implementation of `setValue:forKey:` is invoked for a property the following search pattern is used:
>
> 1. The receiver’s class is searched for an accessor method whose name matches the pattern `set<Key>:`.
> 2. If no accessor is found, and the receiver’s class method `accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` returns `YES`, the receiver is searched for an instance variable whose name matches the pattern `_<key>`, `_is<Key>`, `<key>`, or `is<Key>`, in that order.

The default implementation is to return YES to the `accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` method, so the KVC mechanism is actually getting the values from the `name` and `age` instance variables.

Comment: For this reason, I strongly recommend that one overrides `+accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` to return `NO` for all of one's custom classes. The way that KVC accesses instance variables directly is a horrible breach of encapsulation and hides errors.